# Get the parameter values

Tags: php, parameters, get

I have multiple php files, and I want to merge all the files into one file. All the files come with parameters. If a certain file matches the parameter, that file should execute, else other.

It is not working. Kindly help me.

Comment: It would be nice, if were to include relevant example code.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the "merged" file, make a dictionary keyed on the file to include, and each record containing the array of parameter names for that page, then compare these to the keys of $_GET (or $_REQUEST as appropriate), and include & break when you find a match.

```
$page_parameters = array(
  "person_search.php" => array("first_name","last_name"),
  "edit_post.php" => array("post_id")
);

foreach($page_parameters as $page => $parameters) {
  if($parameters == array_keys($_GET)) {
     include $page;
     break;
  }
}
```

In this example, if a request comes in with `?first_name=bill&last_name=wilson` it will get passes to person_search.php, and if it comes with `?post_id=3121`, it will get passed to edit_post.php

Answer (score 1):

I assume your files are like:

01.php

```
<?php
echo $_GET["var1"];
?>
```

02.php

```
<?php
echo $_GET["var2"];
?>
```

03.php

```
<?php
echo $_GET["var3"];
?>
```

Then, your final.php can be:

```
<?php

//file 01.php
if(isset($_GET["var1"]){
    echo $_GET["var1"];
    exit();
}

//file 02.php
if(isset($_GET["var2"]){
    echo $_GET["var2"];
    exit();
}

//file 03.php
if(isset($_GET["var3"]){
    echo $_GET["var3"];
    exit();
}

?>
```

Ofcourse it will be not that simple, unless you post some relevant code.

**UPDATE:** Based on your comment,

Accessing first file: `read.php?param=dread`
Accessing second File: `read.php?param=dread2` *(My Guess)*

In `read.php`:

```
if(isset($_Get['param'])){
    if($param == 'dread'){
        //mycode;
    }
}
```

You could use this code in `read.php`:

```
if(isset($_Get['param'])){

$param = $_Get['param'];

    if($param == 'dread'){
        //your code for 'dread'
    }
    if($param == 'dread2'){
        //your code for 'dread2'
    }
} else { // if(isset($_Get['param'])) ENDS
     // your code for the case if $param value is not pre-defined.
} //else ENDS
```

Comment: In my first file i am using 'read.php?param=dread' to pass the parameter values & in read.php i am using if(isset($_Get['param'])){if(param == 'dread'){//mycode}}}

Comment: @Abhinav Please provide code in your original question, by editing it.

Comment: Hello,exactly i want the same thing,in this case only first file(dread) is called & dread2 is not calling.I am using this code if($_GET['param'] == 'dread'){}esleif($_GET['param'] == 'dread2'){}else {},here only dread is called,dread2 is not called

Comment: One more thing i want to share is that in my project all the files are called at a time.

Comment: @Abhinav Sorry, I din't get you? Could you explain more and add dome sample code / Data flow in your question above by editing it?

Comment: @Abinav also provide me the `read.php` URL you are using, or you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Query string to check file. eg: `my~url.com?file=one` in php `if(GET['file'] == 'one'] //execute that file...`